# Ubuntu still shuts down after I plugged my charger in

Tags: unity, power-management

On Kubuntu when my battery is dying and I plug my charger in, it says "All suspensions have been cancelled." On Ubuntu or more accurately, Unity-based distors, it still shuts down after plug in my laptop to the charger which insanely stupid. How can I change this?

Comment: Are you plugging it in within 5-15 seconds (I'm not sure what the exact timeout is)? Also, I don't have this problem with Ubuntu GNOME, likely making this a Unity bug.

Comment: I also know that the problem has persisted since at least 12.10, when I switched from Unity to GNOME.

Comment: Can you provide the output of: `gsettings list-recursively  org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power` ?